# Part name: what is this attachment point for on my new Cube carbon frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames

I've got a new fully today, and there is one attachment point on the frame that I cannot identify. Perhaps it's a silly question, but I've given up after 20 minutes of googling :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a cable guide, maybe for a dropped seat post cable?

Comment: Here is [an image](https://ep1.pinkbike.org/p5pb12256595/p5pb12256595.jpg) of the mount in use. not sure what the part is. Looks like it may be for a chain guide. Someone with more mountain bike knowledge could fill in the details.

Comment: Its definitely on the Right Hand side of the bike, not centered.  Which implies its related to the chain and transmission.

Comment: Can we have more information about the bike, model and year?

Comment: @george https://www.bikester.ch/cube-stereo-160-c62-tm-carbonnorange-692367.html

Comment: @ivanhoe1982 thanks, yes Jonathon is correct, if you look at the stereo 160 SL it has a front derailleur bolted on. in the same place, at a similar angle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is for mounting a front derailleur. A standard clamp on front derailleur will not fit on that seattube, so an alternative mount point is needed.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems much too high for that. Looking at my road bike (so, sure, not an MTB), the front derailleur mount is only a couple of centimetres above the height of the big chain-ring, whereas that mount seems to be almost a whole crank-length above the admittedly very small chain ring.

Comment: Direct mount mounting point is quite high and the derailleur reaches downward from there. Check for pictures at for example https://www.bikeradar.com/mtb/gear/article/sram-and-shimano-front-derailleur-types-and-mounts-explained-44397/

Comment: @ojs OK. But meh to bikeradar. They refuse to let me view their site with an ad blocker and, if I take the option of watching one ad to get an hour's ad-free access (which sounds like a great idea), they just waste my time by showing a 30s unskippable ad for... themselves.

Comment: Looks like there's already a chain keeper in place, which is likely mounted to the BB.